# Where pdf files are saved when opened in browser?

Tags: pdf, caching, browser

I have few questions:

- Where pdf files are saved when opened in browser?
- Is it possible when i open pdf in Chrome, access that file somewhere
  in my pc system?

Answer (score -1):

They are stored at this path `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\` in Windows. Run this command `%TEMP%` in the run dialog box to visit the folder.